# asp.net c# multiple conditions in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

in my gridview I have a single condition inside and it is working fine as shown below:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# 
//if
Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]) == "en" ? 
//do this
Eval("emp_en"): 
//else
Eval("emp_ar")
%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and my question is how I can add myltiple conditions which means if condition inside another if condition I tried this code but it gives me error in the last line:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# 
//if
Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]) == "en" ? 
//if
Eval("emp_id") == "1" ? 
//do this
"yes":
//else
"no":
//if
Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]) == "ar" ? 
Eval("emp_id") == "1" ? 
//do this
"1":
//else
"2"
%>
</ItemTemplate>
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you using ternary operator? So where is your  ":" operators?

Comment: yes I am using ternary operator I edited the code

Comment: missing brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one.

```
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]) == "en"
                                      ? Eval("emp_id") == "1"                                                               
                                      ? "yes" 
                                      : Convert.ToString(Session["lang"]) != "ar" 
                                      ? "no"
                                      : Eval("emp_id") == "1" 
                                      ? "1"
                                      : "2" %>
</ItemTemplate>
```